# Transform TableView Tap Location to Cell View Location

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a TapGestureRecognizer on my TableView.
It get me the cell I tapped on.
Next I want to use the tapped location to check if a Label on the cell was tapped.
But of course I have the location relative to the TableView and not to the CellView.
Do you know a convenient way to transform a TableView Location ("World") to the corresponding CellView Location ("Local")?

Thank you very much.

My code so far.
viewDidLoad:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyTableViewController.tapEdit(recognizer:)))
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        tapGesture.delegate = self
```

Tap Method:

```
@objc func tapEdit(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

            let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.tableView)

            if let tapIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) {

                print("Tap Location: \(tapLocation)")
                if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tapIndexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {

                    // of course not working because of the relative location difference
                    if cell.myLabel.frame.contains(tapLocation) {
                        print("Taped cell at \(tapIndexPath). Hit Label.")
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Regards

Comment: I think the better way to implement what you u want is to add tap gesture recognizer on every label on cell creation

Comment: Wouldn't it mean to much overhead if you create n recognizers instead of one?

Comment: not at all. You do too much overhead by yourself. `UITableView` doesn't create as many cells as many rows you return - it creates only rows enough to show to user and reuses it. So don't forget to get indexPath of gesture recognizer's view from tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way if you want to have the local coordinate of that cell, you should use it to get the location of that tap:

```
@objc func tapEdit(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {

    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.tableView)

        if let tapIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) {

            print("Tap Location: \(tapLocation)")
            if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tapIndexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {
                let localLocation = recogniser.location(in: cell)
                // of course not working because of the relative location difference
                if cell.myLabel.frame.contains(localLocation) {
                    print("Taped cell at \(tapIndexPath). Hit Label.")
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```